# Adding new property to items using foreach isn't working

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I have an array within an array.

I'm trying to add a counter to the second array.

I created a new property inside the array, in `console.log` this new property `"actors_count"` shows ok.

When exiting the loop in the second `console.log` the property is still there.

But in my return the property disappears.

Can anybody help me?

```js
var actor_weights = await ActorWeight.findAll({include: {model: Actor, as: 'actors'}});

actor_weights.forEach(element => {
    const actors_count = element.actors.length;
    element.actors_count = actors_count;
    console.log(element.actors_count);
});

console.log(actor_weights.actors_count);

return res.status(200).send({
    actor_weights
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you share a relevant snippet of `actor_weights` array and the desired/actual results? `await ActorWeight.findAll({include: {model: Actor, as: 'actors'}});` doesn't communicate much since I don't have your database. Thanks. `console.log(actor_weights.actors_count);` doesn't make much sense though -- the property is on the elements of the array, not the array itself. Your response should show those elements.

Comment: You're adding `actors_count` to **each element** in the `actor_weights` array